# What are the factors that drive openness in a country?

Tags: economy

What are the factors (positive and negative) that drive openness to trade with other countries in a country (e.g. developed, like USA, vs. developing, like China, country) and will these factors remain a key factor to drive trade openness for the respective country in the future?

So far I researched on stage of development, specialization of each country's skills, degree of trade liberalization and the geographical size.

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean by "openness"?

Comment: I meant openness to trade with other countries

Comment: Last time I checked both China and the United States have plenty of import and export. Could you be a bit more specific about what difference you see between them?

Answer (score 2):

There are two major factors you need to investigate:

1. **Economics**

   The main factor here is the internal demand for goods produced inside the country (China has a major problem in that area) compared to production capacity.
2. **Politics**

   The domestic political power of the producers determines how much effort the country's leadership puts into specific areas of any trade deals (and is frequently industry specific).